# How to get the name of the downloaded file with "drive.files.get ()" (Drive Api v3, Node JS)?

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

This script works perfectly but I don't know how to get the name of the file. Thanks for the help

```
 module.exports.getFile = (id, callback) =>{
    fs.readFile(SECRET_PATH, (err, content) => {
        if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
        authorize(JSON.parse(content), id, (auth, id)=>{
            var dest = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/tmp.mp3'); // temporal name
            const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
            drive.files.get({fileId: id, alt: 'media'},
                {responseType:'stream'},
                function(err, res){
                    res.data.on('end', () => {
                        console.log('done');
                        var filename = 'noname' ; // this is a question
                        fs.rename('/tmp.mp3', '/' + filename + '.mp3', function(err) {
                            if(err) return console.log('error: ', err);
                            callback(filename);
                        });
                    }).on('error', err => {
                        console.log('Error', err);
                    }).pipe(dest);
            }); 
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to download a file by using the original filename on Google Drive using Drive API.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis with Node.js.
- You have already been able to download a file from Google Drive using Drive API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

When `alt=media` is used for the method of Files: get in Drive API, the file metadata is not returned. So in order to retrieve the filename, at first, it retrieves the file metadata using the method of Files: get without `alt=media` in Drive API.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
var dest = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/tmp.mp3'); // temporal name
const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
drive.files.get({fileId: id, alt: 'media'},
    {responseType:'stream'},
    function(err, res){
        res.data.on('end', () => {
            console.log('done');
            var filename = 'noname' ; // this is a question
            fs.rename('/tmp.mp3', '/' + filename + '.mp3', function(err) {
                if(err) return console.log('error: ', err);
                callback(filename);
            });
        }).on('error', err => {
            console.log('Error', err);
        }).pipe(dest);
});
```

To:

```
const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
drive.files.get({ fileId: id }, (er, re) => { // Added
  if (er) {
    console.log(er);
    return;
  }
  var dest = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/' + re.data.name); // Modified
  drive.files.get(
    { fileId: id, alt: "media" },
    { responseType: "stream" },
    function(err, res) {
      res.data
        .on("end", () => { // Modified
          console.log("done");
        })
        .on("error", err => {
          console.log("Error", err);
        })
        .pipe(dest);
    }
  );
});
```

#### References:

- [Download files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)
- [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)

If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: This is the exactly direction I want, and work fine.
thank you so much!!!
you are a genius...

now i feeling idiot =(

(sorry for my English, i a Neanderthal)

c u later...

Comment: @Isma Pena Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.